# Sum of two binary numbers represented by reversed lists in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, binary

Can you help me to get this right? I have a binary representation of the number in a reversed list. Accompanied function `bn` can be used to create the encoded number.

I want to add two binary numbers by carry method, but I can't get it right plus the code is getting messy. The restriction is that one can use only boolean operators and list splicing on the algorithm.

```
# encode binary form of the number, not part of the algo
def bn (n):
  return list(reversed(list(map(lambda x: 1 if x == "1" else 0, "{0:b}".format(n)))))

# main algo to sum two binary numbers
def s(m, n):
  def _ (a, b, c):
    if a and b:
      return [0 if (0 if a[0] == b[0] else 1) == c else 1] + \
             _(a[1:], b[1:], 1 if (c and (a[0] or b[0])) or (a[0] and b[0]) else 0)
    if a:
      return [0 if a[0] == c else 1] + ([1]+a[2:] if c else a[1:])
    if b:
      return [0 if b[0] == c else 1] + ([1]+b[2:] if c else b[1:])
    return [1] if c else []
  return _(m, n, 0)

print(bn(2017), bn(3), s(bn(2017), bn(3)), bn(2017+3))
```

Here the `s(bn(2017), bn(3))`

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

doesn't match with the `bn(2017+3))`

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

as it should.

So I ask help to correct the code plus any optimizations you could make would be appreciated.

#### Addition

To test elementary cases one can use something like:

```
for i in range(0, 12, 2):
  for j in range(0, 12, 3):
    x, y = bn(i+j), s(bn(i), bn(j))
    print(x == y, bn(i), bn(j), "%s + %s = %s %s -> %s" % (i, j, i+j, x, y))
```

But beware, this doesn't catch the problematic addition 2017+3 I gave above...

Comment: @PatrickArtner I don't think this is a homework , and btw it is a good question.

Comment: Please ask a specific question and not that we are doing your homework...

Comment: For starters, I would not use that totally unreadable list-comprehensions that try to cram everything into nested conditional expressions. May try defining some functions?

Comment: Also, using a nested function like this, where you aren't actually creating a closure (or rather, it is closed over no free-variables) is not typical in Python.

Comment: If you have a problem, start by rewriting the code in  a more readable way, avoiding complex expressions, lambdas and unobvious one-liners and list comprehensions. Once you have it working, obfuscate it as much as you wish

Comment: @Arman: `he restriction is that one can use only boolean operators and list splicing on the algorithm.` + `correct the code plus any optimizations you could make would be appreciated.`--> Homework

Comment: @PatrickArtner almost all problems in SO are about _correct my code please_ and _any suggestion for optimization_  , and it's not all , he has written code and sample example , a correct question.

Comment: Please guys, let's try to tackle the problem rather than beat the bushes. In the target environment (Python is just for finding out the algo) I can only use simple conditionals, boolean operators and list processing as stated before. And what comes to more specific questions I could easily use Python docs and Google for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging helps: You had a wrong `c` input for the third iteration. Picture shows end of 2nd iteration

[image: Debugging VS2017]

My testcases showed afterwards that the code for empty `a` or `b` was flawed as well - corrected that after taking the screenshot of debugging the `c` error.

Fix:

```
def s(m, n): 
  def _ (a, b, c):  
    if a and b: 
      return [0 if (0 if a[0] == b[0] else 1) == c else 1] + \
             _(a[1:], b[1:], 1 if (c and (a[0] or b[0])) or (a[0] and b[0]) and not c else 0) # error here
    if a:
      return [0 if a[0] == c else 1] + (_(a[1:],[1],0) if ((a[0] == c) and c) else a[1:]) # error here as well
    if b:
      return [0 if b[0] == c else 1] + (_([1],b[1:],0) if ((b[0] == c) and c) else b[1:]) # error here as well
    return [1] if c else []

  return _(m, n, 0)

# TESTING - till 255 + 255

for a in range(255):
    for b in range(255):
        if( s( bn(a),bn(b) ) == bn(a+b)):
            continue;
        else:
            print("error for a = ",a," and b=",b)
            print(bn(a), " + " , bn(b)," = ", bn(a+b), " ---- not: ", s( bn(a),bn(b) ))

print ("done")
```

Edit:

You can simplify 2 last cases:

```
if a:
  return _(a,[c],0) if c else a 
if b:
  return _(b,[c],0) if c else b
```

Comment: Looks promising. I also found that `if a and if b` branches requires  recursive callbacks. And actually I was playing with `not c` on the very same place you made it. Thanks for valuable contribution.

Comment: @MarkokraM simplification see edit, less total loops and less control structs

Comment: Now thats nearer to beautiful now! Btw. `d =` is not needed there, was probably for debugging only... but good lift up, because it was the XOR gate I was utilizing there.

Comment: @ patrick-artner : I have yet another similar algo, which I think has right output, but again two lines could probably be optimized and simplified. Would you mind to check it, on a private chat or somewhere?

Comment: @MarkokraM Do it as a new questions, I ll have a look later

Comment: Great, I did it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546037/multiplying-binary-numbers-digit-by-digit-and-carry-method-in-python

Comment: But this is a code review topic to be more precise, so I moved it to: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/181556/multiplying-binary-numbers-digit-by-digit-and-carry-method-in-python